# How can I deploy to Elastic Beanstalk using TFS 2017?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, tfs, continuous-integration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a website on elastic beanstalk that I currently use the AWS toolkit to deploy to.  I have a new tfs server that I'm getting CI set up on.  How can I have a bean stalk deploy launch out of TFS as a build step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS provide an [extension to Visual Studio](https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/?nc1=h_ls) to make interacting with your AWS services easy, including deploying to a Beanstalk environment, which is [the recommended way of deploying to a Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-toolkit.html#create_deploy_NET.sdlc.deploy).

The **AWS Toolkit** for Visual Studio includes a deployment tool, a command line tool that provides the same functionality as the deployment wizard in the AWS Toolkit. You can use the deployment tool in your build pipeline or in other scripts to automate deployments to Elastic Beanstalk.

So just use **AWSDeploy.exe** --the command line deployment tool which you can wire up to TFS. Another way is using [AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/)  lets developers and administrators manage their AWS services from the Windows PowerShell scripting environment.

Comment: I've been using Visual Studio to deploy manually, looks like I'll have to add a CLI task to my build steps and wire up AWSDeploy.exe next.  Shame there isn't a web deploy task for AWS in TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial on how to achieve this.

How to Integrate AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) or (VSTS)(for IIS websites/batch jobs you can use this)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRLZZefLDqU